# Can't finally perform HTTP POST request

Tags: android, http, post

I work on my first Android application and I have some great problems with trying to make HTTP POST request and receive response. These are few facts:

1. I have INTERNET permission in AndroidManifest.xml:
    `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`
2. I tried many solutions. Solutions with URLConnection or HttpURLConnection don't work because they return empty string. Solution with HttpClient and HttpPost fails on execute() - I was googling for an hour but didn't find out how to fix that.
3. There **is** internet connection. But I don't know how to fix my problem and finally to *send HTTP POST request.*

**upd:** e.g. this code makes my program crash:

```
public static APIResponse getResponse(String action, Map<String, String> params) throws IOException {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://google.com");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
    return null;
}
```

**upd 2:** it works on my phone but doesn't work on emulator! how to fix that behaviour on emulator?

**upd 3:** fixed.

Comment: First off all you can put your code here, so people can help you with your problem, it might be just a simple UrlEncoding or a simple client configuration.

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505930/make-in-http-request-with-android

Comment: @TomDignan no, there's GET there and that solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: I solved my problem. It works on my phone but crashes on the emulator.
However, can anyone help me how to fix that? I want to test my programs on emulator.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [example for HTTP Post](http://www.vogella.com/articles/ApacheHttpClient/article.html#example_post)

You should also employ [fiddler2](http://fiddler2.org) to help debug your HTTP messages.

Also please note that you are not catching all exceptions properly ... you can add a generic catch statement at the end to prevent your app from crashing and help you figure out where the problem lies.  Could be a timeout or similar.

Comment: Your comment indicated that you still have a crashing problem ... adding a generic excpetion catch will prevent that from happening.  Use Log statements to find out what is happening.